Customized FOrmel in google sheets to mark the current calendar week of the current year
I am currently working on a solution to only mark my crurrent week of the current year on a google sheets with multiple year entries of the same type.
Right now I am using the Customized Formula :
=CALENDARWEEK(TODAY()) = CALENDARWEEK($A4)
My Problem is, that it also marks the current week of all the other year entries for example the week of 2018 on top of the current one in 2024.
Is there an easy way to fix this? Cut of the current Look


You may try:
=(weeknum($A4)=weeknum(now()))*(year($A4)=year(now()))

